# Exit MenuItem Is Forever Disabled

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I have a Exit menu item in a WPF application. When I moved the project over to utilize Caliburn Micro it has become disabled when launching the application.

```
<MenuItem Header="E_xit" InputGestureText="Alt+F4"
          Command="ApplicationCommands.Close"/>
```

Even adding `IsEnabled="True"` does nothing. If I remove the command `Command="ApplicationCommands.Close"`, the menu item is enabled on startup (but obviously I want the Close command to remain attached).

My guess is there must be some kind of method or property I'm not aware of, or maybe I am not initializing the main window properly? Here is my AppBootstrapper:

```
public class AppBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
    SimpleContainer container;

    public AppBootstrapper()
    {
        Start();
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        container = new SimpleContainer();

        container.Singleton<IWindowManager, WindowManager>();
        container.Singleton<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();
        container.PerRequest<IShell, MainWindowViewModel>();

        var currentParser = Parser.CreateTrigger;
        Parser.CreateTrigger = (target, triggerText) => ShortcutParser.CanParse(triggerText)
            ? ShortcutParser.CreateTrigger(triggerText)
            : currentParser(target, triggerText);

    }

    protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
    {
        var instance = container.GetInstance(service, key);
        if (instance != null)
            return instance;

        throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not locate any instances.");
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
    {
        return container.GetAllInstances(service);
    }

    protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
    {
        container.BuildUp(instance);
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayRootViewFor<IShell>();
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> SelectAssemblies() {
        return new[] {
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you haven't set [CommandBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandbinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `ApplicationCommands.Close`.

In case CommandBinding could not be found, command will always return *false from CanExecute method*. So, to enable command you have to:

- First, create CommandBinding at root element (may be at window) or at any parent element which needs to handle this command.
- Second, provide `CanExecute` handler in that command binding and set `e.CanExecute` to `True` in that handler based on condition where you want to enable this menuItem.

Small sample to achieve what i said above:

```
<TextBox>
  <TextBox.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Close" 
                    Executed="CommandBinding_Executed" 
                    CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute"/>
  </TextBox.CommandBindings>
  <TextBox.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
      <MenuItem Header="E_xit" InputGestureText="Alt+F4" 
                Command="ApplicationCommands.Close"/>
    </ContextMenu>
  </TextBox.ContextMenu>
</TextBox>
```

and in code behind handlers:

```
private void CommandBinding_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{

}

private void CommandBinding_CanExecute(object sender,
                                       CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   e.CanExecute = true; <-- Set this to true to enable bindings.
}
```

You can read more about it here - [How to enable a Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753200%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Commanding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: `ApplicationCommands.Close` is a built-in RoutedUICommand. Notice that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.close(v=vs.110).aspx) its example does not include any implementation of CommandBinding?

Comment: Unless is it necessary to implement the command when using Caliburn Micro? In vanilla WPF, the exit command exits the application as expected.

Comment: The example there isn't for Close - it's for Paste and in that example the Textbox handles that when it's got keyboard focus. Notice in [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753200(v=vs.110).aspx) they do handle CanExecute.

Comment: @AquaGeneral - I don't think it's possible with CommandBinding in place. Have you checked the first link I posted in answer and also which AndrewS mentioned in his comments where they have used CommandBidning at window?

Comment: You're both right! I never challenged if the Close command does anything my itself. When I said it was working before, I had a simple event handler for the MenuItem. Some of the most confusing problems to me are almost always caused by something simple.

Comment: The important point is to have a CommandBinding, implementing CanExecute is optional